# How do I perform low level I/O on a Linux device file in Python?

Tags: python, linux, posix

I have a device which returns a string in response to commands written to the device file. I am able to write commands to the device and read the return string in C with code that looks like:

```
int dev = open("/dev/USBDev251", O_RDWR);
write(dev, data, sizeof(data));
read(dev, buff, 16);
```

I am trying to do the same in Python with:

```
dev = os.open("/dev/USBDev251", os.O_RDWR)
os.write(dev, data)
os.read(dev, 16)
```

The write is successful, but only an empty string is returned. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does os.write return the expected number of bytes you wanted to write?

Comment: @hogliux, Yes the write is successful.

Comment: Are you sure that the device actually returns something back?

Comment: I'm looking through the source code of `os.open`, `os.write` and `os.read` at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Modules/posixmodule.c#l6428 and I cannot see why it shouldn't work. Are you printing the return-value of os.read?

Comment: After writing data to the disk, the position of the file descriptor would be at the end of data (numerically equal to length of data). Since fd is at the end of file, empty string is returned. lseek should be used to move the file descriptor back to its initial position before reading the contents.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, this would be true for a regular file on disk but not necessarily for device files. Also, the poster says that the C code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the device driver. The `read()` method registered with the driver's `file_operations` invoked `copy_to_user()` but then returned `0` instead of the number of bytes copied to userspace.

The C code above *"worked"* because it didn't actually check the return value of `read()` and `buff` was getting populated with the response.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [`os.write` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.write):

> **Note:** This function is intended for low-level I/O and must be applied to a file descriptor as returned by `os.open()` or `pipe()`. To write a “file object” returned by the built-in function `open()` or by `popen()` or `fdopen()`, or `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`, use its `write()` method.

You shouldn't be mixing and matching here.  If you use the global function `open()` to open a file, then you must only use the file object's `read()` and `write()` methods.  Conversely, if you use `os.open()` to open a file, then you must only use `os.read()` and `os.write()`.

So, try replacing your call to `open()` with `os.open()`; or, keep the `open()` call, and replace `os.write(dev, ...)` with `dev.write(...)` and replace `os.read(dev, ...)` with `dev.read(...)`.

Comment: My apologies. I was in fact using os.open(). Corrected the question.

Answer (score 7):

Add an `os.lseek()` to seek back to the beginning of the string you wrote.  Currently you wrote 16 bytes which advanced the pointer. When you read, you start reading at the current pointer so you need to back it up to the start of what you wrote.

This worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

data = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
dev = os.open("/dev/sdp1", os.O_RDWR)
os.write(dev,data)
os.lseek(dev,0,os.SEEK_SET)
print os.read(dev,16)
```