# In Python, how to open a file for writing, but do not create it if the file does not exist?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, io

The file is a device under `/dev`. I don't want to mess things up so if the file does not exist, I should not create it. How to handle this in Python?

I hope this problem be solved by `open` method. That is, it should throw an IOError like mode "r" when the file does not exist. Don't redirect the question to "check if a file exists".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to do this. 
Either

```
from os.path import exists
if exists(my_file_path):
    my_file = open(my_file_path, 'w+')
```

if you need to trigger things based on the file existing, that's the best way.

Otherwise, just do `open(file_path, 'r+')`

Comment: Thanks. BTW, can you remove the "duplicate" suggestion? I don't think this question is duplicate.

Comment: @bfrgzju I cannot. After you clarified, it's really a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r but as I'm not a mod, I cannot clear a flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

if os.path.exists(dev):
    fd = os.open(dev, os.O_WRONLY) # or open(dev, 'wb+')
    ...
```

Also check [How to perform low level I/O on Linux device file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424393/how-to-perform-low-level-i-o-on-linux-device-file-in-python)

Comment: Using mode "w" will truncate the file to 0 length and then start writing.

Comment: that would be a device not a file

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple python script that shows the files in a directory, where their file is and whether the real file exists or not

```
import os

def get_file_existency(filename, directory):
 path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
 realpath = os.path.realpath(path)
 exists = os.path.exists(path)
 if exists:
   file = open(realpath, 'w')
 else:
   file = open(realpath, 'r')
```